# MVC "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error" only on IE browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We have got something weird issue "Object reference not set to an instance of an object error" only on IE & Edge browser. Also It happens only on the production server which we as a developers have no direct access to check.

**Code for Redirection**

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "DashBoard", new { Area = "DashBoard" });
```

**Code for DashBoard action**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Code for BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        string cultureName = null;
        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = Request.UserLanguages[0]; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureName))
            cultureName = "en-US";

        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = CultureHelper.GetValidCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

        //Modify current thread's culture            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);


        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

As per the browser error screenshot, the browser URL shows that it got redirected to `www.test.com/DashBoard/DashBoard` but with Object reference error page.

**Error screenshot**

[image: Error screenshot]

I have got NO clue from the stacktrace. It will be really helpful if anyone can figure out and tell me what could be wrong.

Comment: What's inside `Vibrant.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore`? That's not Microsoft code and you must review carefully.

Comment: I have updated my question with `BaseController` logic as well. I am not sure where the issue actually can pop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing any services/other classes in your controller?

Comment: Not services but the external DLL references but everything is properly linked and the same is available too.

Comment: Cant be sure without looking at your code, but check your controller constructor and make sure you initialize all dependencies if you have any, also make sure you register them with dependency injection resolver like Unity...

Comment: All seems to be fine and we have deployed the same source to many clients and they had no problem with IE specific error like this one. But others using upgraded Windows server 2012 and higher IIS version 8.0.